# bogus first syscall argument reported for 32-bit processes on Linux x86_64?

Tags: linux-kernel

On Linux x86_64 systems (at least RHEL 6.4 running 2.6.32), the first syscall argument reported by `/proc/pid/syscall` for 32-bit processes seems to be bogus ... I'd like to determine why.

For example, if a process is blocked doing openat(AT_FDCWD, ...), I see the following in `/proc/pid/syscall` ...

64-bit:

```
257 0xffffffffffffff9c ...
```

32-bit:

```
295 0xffffffff810495c0 ...
```

`AT_FD_CWD == -100 == 0xffffffffffffff9c`, so the 64-bit case looks right, but the value for 32-bit seems to have been clobbered (the other arguments look right).

I know that I can find a struct pt_regs at the top of the stack, and I can find it via ...

```
#define task_pt_regs(tsk)       ((struct pt_regs *)(tsk)->thread.sp0 - 1)
```

I see the bogus value there.

However ... strace seems to be able to find the correct value of the first argument even in the 32-bit case.  It does ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER), which AFAIK just looks at the same struct pt_regs.

I must be missing something ... what magic happens for strace that allows it to see valid register values via PTRACE_PEEKUSER?  What happens to clobber the first argument as seen via `/proc/pid/syscall`?